# Get rid of a certain variable in a fraction's numerator

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

Consider expression $\frac{a - b}{a + b}$. When I apply $FullSimplify[\frac{a - b}{a + b}]$, I get $-1 + \frac{2a}{a+b}$, effectively getting rid of $b$ in the numerator. However, I want to get rid of $a$ and get $1 - \frac{2b}{a+b}$. How do I do this?

In general, I have a more complicated fraction, with multiple variables (and $FullSimplify$ simply does nothing). You can assume that the variable I want to get rid of participates linearly in both numerator and denominator (but its coefficients can be mildly complicated expressions in terms of other variables).

Comment: `FullSimplify[(a - b)/(a + b) /. a -> d] /. d -> a` answers your question as written but is not very satisfying.  In general, the user's idea of simplification often differs from Mathematica's idea..  Using a combination of `Collect` and `FullSimplify` sometimes is useful.  By the way, I would have expected `cf[e_] := LeafCount[e] + 100 Count[e, a, {0, Infinity}]; FullSimplify[(a - b)/(a + b), ComplexityFunction -> cf]` to solve your specific problem, but it does not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
PolQuotient[num_, den_, var_] := PolynomialQuotient[num, den, var] + 1/den*PolynomialRemainder[num, den, var]
```

Test:

```
PolQuotient[a - b, a + b, a]
(*1 - (2 b)/(a + b)*)
```

**Improving the above function:**

```
  PolyQR[expr_, var_, opts___] := Block[{num, den, pq, pr, pqr},
  num := Numerator[expr];
  den := Denominator[expr];
  pq := PolynomialQuotient[num, den, var];
  pr := PolynomialRemainder[num, den, var]/den;
  pqr := pq + pr;
  Return[
  Piecewise[{{pqr, opts === None}, {pq, opts === "Quotient"},{pr, 
  opts === "Remainder"}}]];];
```

Test:

```
  expr = (a - b)/(a + b);
  PolyQR[expr, a]
  (*1 - (2 b)/(a + b)*)
  PolyQR[expr, a, "Quotient"]
  (*1*)
  PolyQR[expr, a, "Remainder"]
  (*-((2 b)/(a + b))*)
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution is great for me, it also solves some other issues by explicitly separating the integer and the fractional parts.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

expr = (a - b)/(a + b);

expr // FullSimplify

(* -1 + (2 a)/(a + b) *)
```

The form of the result is determined by the canonical order of the variables. You can temporarily change the order through substitution

```
expr2 = (expr /. a -> c // FullSimplify) /. c -> a

(* 1 - (2 b)/(a + b) *)

expr2 == expr // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's good to know. Unfortunately, it fails for me when my fractions are more complicated (and `FullSimplify` doesn't do anything at all).